# What is the default value of fontSet in Angular Material icons?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some custom icons in my app which are rendered [by setting the fontSet property](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIcon)

```
<mat-icon fontSet="myFont" fontIcon="my-icon"></mat-icon>
```

Now, I would like to be consistent and render the Angular Material icons using their font set like so

```
<mat-icon fontSet="md" fontIcon="add"></mat-icon>
```

but it doesn't work. So I want to know what is the default value of `fontSet` in Angular Material icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in order to use fontSet you must declare your custom font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('path.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

the you have 2 options to use it with angular Mat-Icon

1) class to apply

```
.MyIconClass
{
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily' !important;
}
```

2) Register to AppComponent

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
   iconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('MyFontFamily', 'MyIconClass');
}
```

Then you will be able to show the icon:

```
<mat-icon fontSet="MyIconClass" fontIcon="LigatureOrUnicodeToDisplay"></mat-icon>
```

or

```
<mat-icon fontSet="MyIconClass">LigatureOrUnicodeToDisplay</mat-icon>
```

If you are like me, and dont want to have more params, just replace the .material-icons with your own font.

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
...
}
```

and then you will be able to use it like this

> LigatureToDisplay

which i love.

You can use this link to create you own icons collection with svg.

https://icomoon.io

happy coding.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I wanted to write all the icons (Material and custom) using either `<mat-icon fontSet="md" fontIcon="add"></mat-icon>` or `<mat-icon fontSet="md">add</mat-icon>`, but the second syntax is not a valid one

Comment: the default value of fontSet is material-icons, but you need to declare is in your css

Comment: How do I declare it in my css?

Comment: just like a regular class, just add the font settings...like this

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}

Comment: and then you can be consistent and send that class name as fontSet and everything will look the same

Comment: what I did was create my own icon component! and trigger an if.. using either svg, custom glyph font, materials or font-awesome! so I have all in one